# Can we combine conditional statements using column indexes in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**For the following dataframe:**

---

**Headers:** Name   P1  P2  P3

---

**L1:** A   1   0   2

---

**L2:** B   1   1   1

---

**L3:** C   0   5   6

I want to get yes where all P1, P2 and P3 are greater than 0.

Currently I am using either of the following methods:

---

**Method1:**

```
df['Check']= np.where((df['P1'] > 0) & (df['P2'] > 0) & (df['P3'] > 0),'Yes','No')
```

**Method2:**

```
df.loc[(df['P1'] > 0) & (df['P2'] > 0) & (df['P3'] > 0), 'Check'] = "Yes"
```

I have a large dataset with a lot of columns where the conditions are to be applied.

Is there a shorter alternative to the multiple ***&*** conditions, wherein I won't have to write the conditions for each and every variable and instead use a combined index range for the multiple columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check all `True`s per rows:

```
cols = ['P1','P2','P3']
df['Check']= np.where((df[cols] > 0).all(axis=1),'Yes','No')
print (df)
  Name  P1  P2  P3 Check
0    A   1   0   2    No
1    B   1   1   1   Yes
2    C   0   5   6    No

print ((df[cols] > 0))
      P1     P2    P3
0   True  False  True
1   True   True  True
2  False   True  True

print ((df[cols] > 0).all(axis=1))
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Simpler might be `df[cols].astype(bool)` ?

Comment: @jpp - Yes, it depends of dta.

Comment: Thanks guys. Worked like a charm.. :)